# How can I get a list of all the venues that are "Managed" from Foursquare API

Tags: ios, foursquare

I am currently using Foursquare API to query out a list of venues.

However, I need to query out some specific venue that are "managed". (Managed means the venues whose owners have a Foursquare account and use Foursquare for the business)

However, I can't use the way in "https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/managed" to get  the result because it is only for the current user.

I check the venue search response and found that there is a value called "verified"(https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/venue). Is that means "managed"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "verified" attribute indicates that the venue has been claimed by its owner. See https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/venue for more information.